# Unwanted output

Tags: python, output

This is my code:

```
j = [['4', '5'], ['1', '1'], ['1', '5'], ['3', '4'], ['3', '1']]
k = [['5', '2'], ['4', '2'], ['2', '4'], ['3', '3'], ['4', '3']]
t = [[None] *2] *50
indexPointer = 0

for coord in j:
    print(coord)
    for number in coord:
        t[indexPointer][0] = number
        indexPointer += 1
indexPointer = 0
for coord in k:
    for number in coord:
        t[indexPointer][1] = number
        indexPointer += 1
print(t)
```

The output should be:

```
[['4','5'],['5','2'],['1','4'],['1','2'],['1','2'],['5','4'],['3','3'],['4','3'],['3','4'],['1','3']]
```

The output is:

```
[['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '3']]
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: You are creating a list `t` which contains 50 references to *one* nested list `[None, None]`. See the duplicate on how to create unique lists instead.

Comment: `t = [[None] *2 for _ in range(50)]` will be better.

Comment: That worked. Thank you!

Comment: You can also simply use zip(j, k).